# Django change user group to oneToOne Field

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I want to create multiple levels of users in my application developed using django1.6 and python 3.2.  I inserted the levels in auth_group table. but in the  add user page of Django Admin  I can assign one user to more than one group(multiselect Group values). Actually I want is one user to one Group only.

Please reply me.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely change the django core is not an option. You shouldn't never do it because in the future you will have problems to update your system to the new django versions,

I can't see clearly why you want to do it but if you really think is a good implementation you should extend your Authentication model to implement what you need:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually I want is Django admin page customization to add only one group to one user..  Normally we can add more than one group to one user... I need an onToOne Relationship...